# jQuery or Javascript regular expression to clean up date parameter in url

Tags: javascript, jquery, grails

My regular expression chops are very rough and I could use a hand trying to clean up this url. It doesn't have to be a regular expression if there is an easier way to go about this.

```
&EnrolledDate=date.struct&EnrolledDate_day=14&EnrolledDate_month=3&EnrolledDate_year=2013&
```

For some reason, the date picker in a Grails project is three separate fields instead of a nice calendar, but OK, we can deal with three fields from the jQuery side.

I need this piece of the URL to transform into something like

```
&EnrollDate=14-MAR-2013&
```

Where the name EnrollDate can change to whatever, it just needs to be the characters from the first "&" to the first "=".

I also can't figure out why on the html page, the options for the month are spelled out, but jQuery serializes them into the index position?

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to hard-code the variable part, and the month part... hope it helps in anyway...

```
            var str="&EnrolledDate=date.struct&EnrolledDate_day=14&EnrolledDate_month=3&EnrolledDate_year=2013&";
            var gmatches=str.match(/&Enrolled[^=]*?=[^&a-zA-Z]+/g);
            var string=[];
            int i;
            //This is for capturing the dates parts.
            for(i in gmatches){
                string.push(gmatches[i].match(/&Enrolled(.*?)=([^&][0-9]*)/i)[2]);
            }
            //for getting the months
            var months=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
            string[1]=months[(parseInt(string[1])-1)];
            var res="&name="+string.join('-')+"&";
            //res -> &name=14-Mar-2013&
```